# Bash script to switch the user

Tags: linux, bash

I am having a cent-OS server with 5 accounts: `developer`, `user1` ,`user2` ,`user3` and `user4`. All the user home directories are under `/home` like `/home/developer`, `/home/user1`, `/home/user2`, `/home/user3` and `/home/user4`. I want to create a 4 scripts: `user1.sh`, `user2.sh`, `user3.sh` and `user4.sh` inside the `/home/developer` folder. When the user `developer` run the script `user1.sh`, he switches to the `user1` and `cd` to the home directory of `user1` (`/home/user1`) and so on for the remaining scripts. The idea behind is to keep the developer from the root access and allow switch to other user's home directory by simple executing a command with that user's name. Is it possible?

Comment: You do not need any script for this. Simply use `su -l <user>` and all is fine. If you insist on this being too complex you can make an alias for it. If you are bothered with typing a password, then take a look at the `sudo` command and it's (very insecure) `NOPASSWD` option.

Comment: @arkascha How can I set the visudo to allow the user 'developer' to switch to all other users except root without entering password ?

Comment: Did you real the manual? Seems not, because it is explained in there. Have a try using `man sudo` and `man sudoers`. You really should try finding that out yourself. This is the best, easiest and most efficient way to learn your way around unix like systems: reading the man pages and trying things out yourself.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I suppose you're looking at `su - otherUser`

Of course, you'll have to provide the password of the other user.

I suppose that something like `sudo su - otherUser` could work but I haven't tried

Comment: I use this in the entrypoint point script of a `Dockerfile` and for some reason it stops the script and is not allowing the script to move on. Any clue why?

Comment: I would bet its prompting you to type your password

Comment: How to provide the password in that same line, with no prompt?